Jupyter notebook suddenly stopped working

I noticed that my notebook suddenly stoped working. I created this new file to test it and it appears that the cell doesn't even recognize comands like import (that usually turns green when typed). I noticed the "No Kernel" in the corner and tried selecting the Python 3 version but it goes back to "No Kernel" as soon as I try to run the code again.
Already tried to update python, Jupyter notebook and IPython but none of that seems to work...

first run jupyter in console/terminal to see if it display error messages.

I use the miniconda3. It displays a mensage "usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]
Jupyter: Interactive Computing..." with some more comand options.

Ok, I can't explain what exactly made it work back but it did after I updated both conda and ipython in my miniconda terminal. I'll let the question active for anyone willing to answer with more details or to simple use the same solution that I did.
